# How convert string to hash with array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

How convert this string (it's one string from db) to hash with array?

```
---
fl:
- 
- 500.0
price:
- 2162.72
- 2152.72
period:
- 
- 3 weeks
```

I got this data by doing this:

```
changes_data = box.changes.to_hash
changes_data.each do |key, val|
  if val[0].eql? val[1]
    changes_data.delete(key)
  else
    changes_data[key] = val.to_a
  end
end
```

But now I don't know how to convert back.
I want get maybe this:

```
{:fl => ['0', '500.0'], :price=>['2162.72','2152.72'],.......}
```

or convert to object `box`

Comment: are you using an ORM to comment to the database (such as ActiveRecord)?

Comment: I think not. If you have understood correctly.

Comment: No. I have two objects. They were compared, and the difference is sent to the database in a separate .

Comment: Yes, it seems you are right. This YML. Sorry, I just started to learn.

Comment: Are you using `serialize` in your model or are you just throwing some random Hash into a string column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your data is just YAML. So you can do this:

```
require 'yaml'

serialized_str = ... # retrieve the serialized string from the database
deserialized_hash = YAML.parse(serialized_str).to_ruby

deserialized_hash.class # => Hash
```

[Ruby Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html)